# Automate LGE Tool with AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I want to load [LGE Tool](http://www.lgtool.net/site/features.html) from an AutoIt script, then go to the tab "Remote Services". I am using this code:

```
$program = "C:\Program Files (x86)\LGE Tool\LGETool.exe"

If ProcessExists($program) = True Then
    MsgBox(0,"","works")
ElseIf ProcessExists($program) = False Then
    Run($program)
EndIf

WinActivate($program)

WinWaitActive("LGE Tool version 1.99")

Send("{^TAB}")
```

The software does load but nothing works after.

Answer (score 1):

Your Send syntax is incorrect...it should be:

```
Send("^{TAB}")
```

I'm assuming that `Control + TAB` works in the program; the software you mentioned is proprietary and requires special drivers, nobody can really test the solution without prerequisites so you've got to be the test point.

Hope this works!
Alex